# How do I log event and context information automatically on AWS Lambda function failures?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to log Lambda function failures in such a way that event and context information is saved so that the event information can, if deemed necessary, later be manually republished to the function's trigger. I do not want to handle this logic in the functions themselves.

What I've tried so far:

- CloudWatch alarms on the error metric. They tell me only that a function has failed.
- Looking in the CloudWatch logs. I only see the coded failure messages emitted
  from each function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such setting, if that's what you're looking for.

If you'd like these properties to be logged, you have to `print` them - only that way they are visible in `CloudWatch` and whatever service that your logs are piped to (logs can be piped to `Elasticsearch` for example, from `CloudWatch`).

However, this can be easily done adding these two lines of code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(context));

  // your code
};
```

As a rule of thumb, logs are the only way for describing what your `lambda` went through at each invocation.